# SugarCRM - Trigger Javascript function when relate field is populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, sugarcrm

I want to trigger some JavaScript when a relate field is populated

I was hoping to find a way of Jquery monitoring the hidden field contact_id and when it changes calling the Javascript function but I'm not sure this is possible

At the moment I changed editviewdefs so that the event triggers onblur

```
Code:

 array (
            'name' => 'contact_name',
            'label' => 'LBL_CONTACT_NAME',
            'customLabel' => '{$MOD.LBL_CONTACT_NAME}:  <span class="required">*</span>',
            'displayParams' => 
            array (
              'initial_filter' => '&account_name_advanced={$fields.account_name.value}&status_advanced=Live',
              'field' => 
              array (
                'onchange' => 'getOpenCases()',
              ),
              'javascript' => 
              array (
                'btn' => ' onblur="getOpenCases()" ',
                'btn_clear' => ' onblur="getOpenCases()" ',
              ),
            ),
            'tabindex' => '11',
          ),
```

But this means the user has to click away from the field before the event is triggered

I want it to happen as soon as contact_id is populated

Is this possible? If so how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a rather convoluted method to check for a change in the hidden input.

I trigger a setInterval function when someone either clicks the button or starts typing into the text field.  I then use jQuery data() to check for any change in the hidden input.  When I change is noticed I run my custom js and then I clear the interval.

All the code is in an external js file.

```
// watch for a change in account ID
$('#btn_account_name').click(function(){
    checkAccountIdChange();
});
$('#account_name').blur(function(){
    checkAccountIdChange();
});

function checkAccountIdChange() {
    var theInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var oldId = $('#account_id').data('oldId');
        var newId = $('#account_id').val();
        if (oldId != newId && newId != '') {
            getAccountData(newId, theInterval);
            $('#account_id').data('oldId', newId);
        }

    }, 500);
}

function getAccountData(id, theInterval) {

    // do your custom js
    clearInterval(theInterval);

}
```

This isn't particularly clean or glamorous but does work.  I'd be keen to see how others get around this.